# Failed to connect to PostgreSQLContainer: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, testcontainers, postgresql-12

Creating my container as:

```
public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:latest");

static {
    container.start();

    System.setProperty("driver-class-name", container.getDriverClassName());
    System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", container.getJdbcUrl());
    System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", container.getUsername());
    System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", container.getPassword());
}
```

I'm trying to enter debug mode after start and check connection, however I keep getting

```
[08001] The connection attempt failed. java.io.EOFException.
```

Full exception trace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.lenovo.edge.controller.UploadControllerTest.whenSelectQueryExecuted_thenResulstsReturned(UploadControllerTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:337)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:411)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    ... 29 more
```

So it's pretty obvious that my application cannot connect to it as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show us what are `container` info

Comment: @YCF_L sure, what exactly do you need?

Comment: all the info please url password username driver

Comment: @YCF_L driver: org.postgresql.Driver, url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32935/test?loggerLevel=OFF, user: test, password: test

Comment: @YCF_L I have default settings as you can see

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: while in the debug mode, try doing "docker ps", checking that the container is running and the port is correct. You can also try to connect to it outside of java, e.g. from CLI, just to make sure that this is not something caused by your firewall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, the problem was container was not able to receive connections, I'm not sure actually why, cos config looks fine for me, but working solution is to initialize container as https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/#database-containers-launched-via-jdbc-url-scheme

So here is example of working solution for me, hope it can help to somebody:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
  "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:12.2:///test?TC_INITSCRIPT=init.sql",
  "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver"
})
abstract class AbstractIntegrationTestCase {

  public static GenericContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:12.2");

  static {
    container.start();
  }

  @Autowired
  protected TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
}
```