# Spring Boot : HikariPool-1 -Exception during pool Initialization

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

i'm a student and learning spring boot on my own. but having issue while trying to connect my data base
always get connection attempt failed error.
trying to run my main class and here is the error.
can anyone help me please

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50659:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\employee\target\classes;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.5.4\postgresql-42.5.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.0.4\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.0.4\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.6\spring-aop-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.19\aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.0.4\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.0.6\spring-jdbc-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.1.7.Final\hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.23\byte-buddy-1.12.23.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.2\jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.2\jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.0\angus-activation-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.2\txw2-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.0\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.10.1\antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.0.3\spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.0.3\spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.0.6\spring-orm-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.6\spring-context-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.0.6\spring-tx-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.6\spring-beans-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.6\slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.0.6\spring-aspects-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.0.4\spring-boot-starter-web-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.0.4\spring-boot-starter-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.0.4\spring-boot-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.0.4\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.0.4\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.5\logback-classic-1.4.5.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.5\logback-core-1.4.5.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.19.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.19.0\log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.6\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.33\snakeyaml-1.33.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.0.4\spring-boot-starter-json-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.14.2\jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.14.2\jackson-annotations-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.14.2\jackson-core-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.14.2\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.14.2\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.14.2\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.0.4\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.5\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.5\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.5.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.5\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.0.6\spring-web-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.10.4\micrometer-observation-1.10.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.10.4\micrometer-commons-1.10.4.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.0.6\spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.6\spring-expression-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.6\spring-core-6.0.6.jar;C:\Users\IBOUKOUN.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.6\spring-jcl-6.0.6.jar" com.homework.employee.EmployeeApplication

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.4)

2023-03-28T04:23:00.922-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] c.homework.employee.EmployeeApplication  : Starting EmployeeApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 20868 (C:\Program Files\employee\target\classes started by IBOUKOUN in C:\Program Files\employee)
2023-03-28T04:23:00.929-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] c.homework.employee.EmployeeApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-28T04:23:01.688-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-28T04:23:01.712-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-03-28T04:23:02.239-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2023-03-28T04:23:02.252-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-28T04:23:02.252-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-28T04:23:02.371-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-28T04:23:02.371-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1370 ms
2023-03-28T04:23:02.537-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-03-28T04:23:02.606-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-03-28T04:23:02.914-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-28T04:23:03.962-05:00 ERROR 20868 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.homework.employee.EmployeeApplication.main(EmployeeApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:467) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:589) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:191) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    ... 48 common frames omitted

2023-03-28T04:23:03.966-05:00  WARN 20868 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.homework.employee.EmployeeApplication.main(EmployeeApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:467) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:589) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:191) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    ... 48 common frames omitted

2023-03-28T04:23:03.984-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2023-03-28T04:23:04.342-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-28T04:23:04.355-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-28T04:23:04.399-05:00  WARN 20868 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-03-28T04:23:04.833-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-28T04:23:04.845-05:00  INFO 20868 --- [           main] c.homework.employee.EmployeeApplication  : Started EmployeeApplication in 4.653 seconds (process running for 5.85)
```

I've already try to reset my dependencies but same thing.
in my other project everything work fine and use port 5432 .
this time am using port 5433 to avoid conflict but still fail.
help me out.

Comment: You should properly format you question.

Comment: You need to set the port as 5432 unless your Postgresql database is set to 5433. If not, then got to Postgresql and change the port.

Comment: Make sure that what port you are using is not already occupied.

Comment: 2023-03-29T23:25:43.327-05:00 ERROR 14992 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: port 5432 is already in use and working fine that is why i use 5433 for this project

Answer (score 0):

Terminal is telling you:

> Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null

I would try for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337360/failed-to-connect-to-postgresqlcontainer-java-io-eofexception) answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).